# Sum Multiple items if condition met

Tags: xslt

This is a document library. I'm trying to have calculations in two fields (**Year 1 Total** and **Year Order Complete**). I'm trying to use the condition "When **Team** = *Axis Deer* or *Some Other Choice* and **DocumentType** = *Task Order* or Modification) use xslt to calculate total to one field (Yellow fields). Then I want to have a calculation of all years (Year 1-1 thru 3-5). that will sum the amounts in yellow (first year numbers). I also only want to be able to see one entry for each team.

In short, I want to be able to sum Initial Year columns (Yellow), up and down and across and then do the same for all subsequent years to be calculated in Where you see the red arrow (last cell first row).

Any suggestions.
[image: graphical representation of what my intent is.]